Streamlit error with streamlit.web.bootstrap: Bad message format Tried to use SessionInfo before it was initialized
Context
I want to debug python 3.11 code for Streamlit 1.32.0 applications using PyCharm as an IDE.
Strategy up to now:
I used streamlit.web import bootstrap as suggested in How to run/debug a streamlit application from an IDE
Example:
The file starter.py
try:
    # for streamlit >= 1.12.1
    from streamlit.web import bootstrap
except ImportError:
    from streamlit import bootstrap

real_script = 'main.py'
bootstrap.run(real_script, f'run.py {real_script}', [], {})

calls
main.py
import streamlit as st

st.text('hello world')

Error I get on the Browser (Firefox)
Bad message format
Tried to use SessionInfo before it was initialized
Further information
I've successfully tried to start the streamlit application using the "non-debug" way
streamlit run main.py

thus the problem seems to be related streamlit.web.bootstrap.

I am having the exact same problem. The linked solution for debugging streamlit apps worked for me in the past, but now this error occurs.

According to the function signature
def run(
main_script_path: str,
is_hello: bool,
args: list[str],
flag_options: dict[str, Any],

) -> None:
I changed the line
bootstrap.run(real_script, f'run.py {real_script}', [], {})

to
bootstrap.run(real_script, False, [], {})

The function expects the path as first parameter and as second parameter a Boolean is_hello . Maybe the functio was changed and expected to strings in the past? With this adjustment it seems to work again.
